# Check if "now()" and timestamp from a db aren't different than 3 days

Tags: postgresql, datetime, elixir, ecto

I'm using Phoenix and Ecto. I need to check if a difference between "now()" and a certain date less than 3 days. Exactly I'm trying this:

```
    {diff_days, {_, _, _}} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(my_user.signed_up_at) |> :calendar.time_difference(:calendar.universal_time)
    if diff_days <= 3 do
      # good to go
      # ....
    end
```

However, this won't for a date older than 3 days and 1 minute, right?

What's the univeral way to check if it's not more but 3 days or 72 hours?

In my database `signed_up_at` is of type `timestamp without timezone`

Comment: Why not do it in the database? Is `signed_up_at` to be interpreted in your session time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.diff/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#diff/3):

```rb
three_days_in_seconds = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60
case DateTime.diff(DateTime.utc_now, my_user.signed_up_at, :second) do
  good when good < three_days_in_seconds ->
    # good to go
  _ ->
    # skip
end
```

Please note, that `:second` is a default value for the third argument in a call to `DateTime.diff/3` and might be omitted.

Comment: as I've said: `my_user.signed_up_at` is **NaiveDateTime**!

Comment: Use [`NaiveDateTime.diff/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#diff/3) then and stop yelling at people who help you.